# Wireless Transformer no C-Wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to install a wireless thermostat but i ran into issue putting in an external thermostat. I have a 2 Stage Cool / 1 Stage heat system.

I have the Red 24V from Air Handler connected to R. I have a external 24 Volt Transformer Hooked up to Rc, and C. I get 27 volts between Rc, and C. However when i tell thermostat to turn on fan nothing happens. If i remove external transformer and jump Rc, and R using AHU transformer everything works fine.

What could be causing this?

[image: Photo of Wiring]

Comment: The external transformer probably doesn't have enough power to pull the relay.  What is the [Volt-Ampere (VA)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt-ampere) rating of the transformer?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. When you say "external transfirmer", you probably mean something like a wall wart.  In that case, it will have an ampere rating not Volt-Ampere.

Comment: Output: AC 24V 300mA. http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/261115137424_1_0_1/1000x1000.jpg

Comment: Any idea what the relay is rated? Or could you include the make and model of the air handler?

Comment: Not home right now to get specifics. But its a Rheem 3 Ton 16 Seer. Im just worried its something complex cause i have a $150 thermostat coming tomorrow.

Comment: Worst comes to worst I guess. I could hook up as follows: Red (24V from Internal Transformer) to Rc, and External to R (Rh) and C. Thus sacrificing heat capability but im in florida so it doesnt really get that cold.

Comment: If it works with the transformer in the air handler (which is 24V 40VA from what I could find), I'd guess the wall wart just doesn't have the power to pull the relay.

Comment: Could I do this then? Leave 24V from Internal Transformer connected to Rc & Jumped to R. And hook up only 1 wire from external transformer to C and cap the other end basically using the neutral?

Comment: Does the concept of Leaving Rc hooked up to 40VA* transformer and hooking up external to Rh and C sound like it would work. I have no use for heat.

Comment: I've seen people on the Internet use only one wire from a wall wart as a `C` wire, but in my opinion it's not the best way to go.  The correct thing to do, is to run a new cable with an additional wire.

Comment: Will one wire with wall wart work? My airhandler is sealed 100% with metal foil tape even the service access panel and its still under warranty

Comment: I've only seen it done on the Internet, so maybe.  I wouldn't do it in my house, especially with the price of a service call from an HVAC company.

Comment: Ok. So it sounds like External Transformer to Rh, and C is the safest option. It wont have enough power to close contact for heat but i will never use it.

Comment: No. The **safest** option, is to pull a new cable.  The external transformer could damage the system, and/or void the warranty.

Comment: Opening the air handler would void warranty thats what im trying to avoid.

Comment: Air Handler Rheem is rhpl-hm3621ja. Where would i find the amp of amps to trigger the relay?

Comment: With the model number, you should be able to find replacement parts online.  You should be able to find a replacement blower relay, which should list all the specs. You might also be able to find owners, installation, and/or maintenance guides online.